# Extend DOM element's functionality

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I select a DOM element and chain a series of actions to the element like this:

```
_my('#maindiv').move(100, 250).fadeOut(1000)
```

I realize jQuery and a host of other libraries do the above but I'm at a bit of loss ...

The actual implementation is not necessary, just the basic skeleton of selecting and chaining.

Comment: Before you go down the route of extending DOM elements, read [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Once you absorb that, you'll work out you need a "wrapper" object that has all the extensions you want and applies them to a set of elements associated with the object. At that stage, you've started to replicate the interface strategy used by most current DOM libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can chain methods:

```
$('#maindiv')
    .css({left: 100, top: 250})
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .addClass('.foo')
    .toggleClass('.inactive', $(this).is(':checked'))
;
```

Check inside these methods to see how to make chaining.

Generally you make function like `function _(selector)` that returns selected element object with all it's new functions inside.

```
function _(selector) {
    var obj = {
        el: document.getElementById(selector),
        css: function (attributes, values) {
            /* ... */

            return obj;
        },
        fadeOut: function (speed) {
            /* ... */

            return obj;
        }
    };

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: He's not looking for jQuery, he's looking for a way to do a similar type of chaining himself.